# Generic printing using a USB port

Tags: linux, printing, operating-system, usb

I am developing on a device that has no printer support natively. I need to print to any printer using a USB port. Is this feasible? Is there any generic standard for all printers to print via USB?

The device runs on Linux/PowerPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.

There's the [USB Printer Class](http://www.usb.org/developers/devclass_docs/usbprint11.pdf) (PDF, 11 pages). It seems to require that the host present data to the printer in either PDL or PCP formats. Remember that USB printers are generally "dumber" than Ethernet-connected printers, and require the host to do more work.

For the embedded world, you might be interested in [Microchip's Application Note AN1233](http://www.eettaiwan.com/STATIC/PDF/200902/20090212_Microchip_AN01.pdf?SOURCES=DOWNLOAD) (PDF, 22 pages), titled "USB Printer Class on an Embedded Host".

Comment: Thanks. Both the docs look real helpful, exactly what I was looking for.