# USB Printing for DOT Matrix POS printer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I was trying to print to an usb printer using usbmanager, the App can detect the printer device but when i run it doesnt print. there are no errors and all passing data is ok.
Printer : Bixolon SRP 275III
Type: USB

```
private async void printReciept()
 {
 UsbManager m_usbManager;
            m_usbManager = (UsbManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.UsbService);

            var deviceList = m_usbManager.DeviceList;
            IEnumerable<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.Values.AsEnumerable();
            UsbDevice m_usbdevice = null;

            if (deviceIterator.Count() > 0)
            {
                var device = deviceIterator.ElementAt(0);
                m_usbdevice = device;
                string ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";
                var mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
                m_usbManager.RequestPermission(m_usbdevice, mPermissionIntent);

                    UsbDeviceConnection deviceConnection = null;
                    try
                    {
                        using (var usbInterface = m_usbdevice.GetInterface(0))
                        {
                            using (var usbEndpoint = usbInterface.GetEndpoint(0))
                            {
                             mEndPoint = usbEndpoint;
                                deviceConnection = m_usbManager.OpenDevice(m_usbdevice);

                                byte[] bytesHello = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello");


                            deviceConnection.BulkTransfer(usbEndpoint, bytesHello, bytesHello.Length, 0);
                         }
                    }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }


            }
       }
```

Comment: how are you passing the intent please show and also the logcat if possible

Comment: Those Bixolon printers have a Java-based SDK (that includes ABI native libraries for printing PDF and images) and they need to be initialized.  You might be able to review their Linux CUPS driver to determine the initialization required and the escape sequences for the different print features, but it would be much easier to create a Xamarin.Android Binding library around their .Jar library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the string to be printed directly to the bulk endpoint, or actually you are doing bulk transfer to the first endpoint found without knowing any of it's characteristics? I think it is a bit more complex than that.

First try to find out whether your printer supports USB printing class or some proprietary implementation. You can do this easily e.g. by connecting the printer to Windows PC and looking from the device manager, [usbdeview](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) or some other similar application.

If it supports printing class, read [this](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/usbprint11a021811.pdf) document and implement your driver based on that (or use the one you may already have in Android). If it only supports proprietary implementation, you need to get the specifications for it or do some reverse engineering.

You may need to learn about [PCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) which may also be needed.

Comment: So far iv'e found out.. the first endpoint was IN... and the 2nd end point is OUT.. iv'e tried to send a string to the 2nd end point..still nothing..iv'e read some code and decompiled some app..just to see how the printing works... yet...nothing..

Comment: You need to find out the language your printer speaks and send that language over the endpoint. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1519308/4025606 is pretty similar to mine, but points out to an additional document also.

Comment: i'm current studying now he docs on the link you given me.. its a big help.. and also i found this... https://www.itechart.com/blog/usb-android-deep-dive-theory-and-practical-example/  can you tell me your opinion on that one.. and if im still on the right path?..thanks

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable explanation of USB basics. You can find lots of specifications and material at USB.org if you want to go deeper into USB in general.

Comment: i got an update, i was able now to print but it seems the BulkTransfer for the printer has a maximum number of bytes to received and the remaining bytes that was pass will be printed on the next BulkTransfer.

Comment: yes, USB is packet based protocol and each endpoint has maximum packet size that is defined in the endpoint descriptor. I am not sure if C# provides some methods to hide this.

Comment: i think mines hold 16 packet size. i was think if i'm gonna pass a load of data to the printer i gonna divide it to 16 packet size first. Is there a function for that process?..im studying usbrequest function right now. Am i on the right track?